# Python how to set a variable to a string

Tags: python, string, variables, integer

so i wanna make it so this thing deletes my first 5 selections for my game im making... im a little new to this so anything is helpful thanks
im getting the error that Selection it no defined,but that is because the %i thing isnt working, can someone help  me get this to work?

```
SelNum=0
while SelNum!=6:
  selection%i.delete() % (int(SelNum))
  SelNum+=1
```

thanks!

Update:

what it should have read was

```
    global SelNum
    try:SelNum
    except:SelNum=0
    def whatever():
        if SelNum!=6:
        selection%i.delete() % (int(SelNum))
        SelNum+=1
        whatever()
```

this would be were selection is equal to a value set somewhere else and the function delete is a function already defined in the game i was doing the coding for, this code would delete six instances of whatever selection was set to, anyways thank! ;)

Comment: Both you code and explanation are so strange that I can't even understand what you have and what you want.

Comment: You haven't included enough information to tell what the problem is.  For starters, what do you expect to happen, and what's actually happening?

Comment: yea i didnt really know much of any python syntax just kinda hoping someone would understand but i know how and why that wouldnt work and why it was bad syntax

Answer (score 1):

You cant.
You are trying to create an class object from a string.
To be more precise let me show you the code

```
class A:
    def delete():
        print "Deleted"

selection1 = A()
selection2 = A()
selection3 = A()
selection4 = A()
selection5 = A()
selection6 = A()

SelNum=0
while SelNum!=6:
  selection%i.delete() % (int(SelNum))
  get.delete()
  SelNum+=1
```

Ouput:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 15, in <module>
    selection%i.delete() % (int(SelNum))
NameError: name 'selection' is not defined
```

The  selection%i will be treated as a string and not as a A() class object.

Comment: ok i posted this a forever and a half ago and i know what i did wrong, this is an invalid syntax because i asked a question without giving background konwledge as to some of the things in the code like the Delete(). but thanks duck for even attempting to fix this crap of a question and thunmbs up for who voted down my question